# Initializing viewmodel with default data from server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

How do we populate data in the knockoutjs view model on the first call to the page? That is, when the View is rendered the first time.

My server View Model class contains a list of objects. I want the knockoutjs view model property to be initialized with this value.

I tried the below code but it fails with the following error:

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type.

This is my code:

```
var mylist = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.list));

 var viewModel = {
     list: ko.observableArray(myList),
 };
```

The standard drop down list works with the same property. Seems like a serialization issue?

```
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.list, new SelectList(Model.list, "id", "name"), "-- select --")
</div>
```

Comment: This thread has several options that might work for you: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/knockoutjs/7MsY8HGVtrc/discussion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a view model which doesn't have circular references otherwise you will not be able to JSON serialize it (`Json.Encode(Model.list)`). I suppose that this `Model.list` property is a collection of some objects which have circular references between them. You will have to remove properties from your view model that are causing those circular references if you want to be able to JSON serialize your model.

Comment: It is EF Entity object list. How does the Html.DropDownList manages it? I guess it just pulls the Id and name at the server, so nothing more to serialize

Comment: @Pinakin Shah, Html.DropDownList doesn't care about circular references. It uses only the element at 1 level of your object hierarchy, whereas in order to serialize an object graph the entire hierarchy needs to be visited. This of course is not possible with JSON or XML.

Comment: Agree. I should only send the required name and value pair from the server.